# Fortran write to same file from inside if statement

Tags: fortran

I am currently working on some fortran code and getting an error of.

```
 `Duplicate statement label 201 at (1) and (2)`
```

My code is long but simplified looks like so:

```
      integer :: y,x,method
      x = 0
      print*, "Please enter a value (1 or 2)." 
      read(*,*) method
          if (method .EQ. 1) then
            x = 10
              do i=1,1000
                 y = x * i
                 Call OtherFile(y,x,i)
                 write(6,201) long,list,of,variables
201      format('OUTPUT: ',i5,1p,7d10.2)
              enddo
              stop
          else if (method .EQ. 2) then
           x = 10
              do i=1,1000
                y = x * i * i
                Call OtherFile(y,x,i)
                write(6,201) long,list,of,variables,
201       format('OUTPUT: ',i5,1p,7d10.2)
            enddo
          stop
        end if
```

*Edit: After posting earlier I realised this code would work. I cannot post the original work so I have best tried to recreate the problem.*
*Edit2: I have made the mistake in labelling this as Fortran77, it is infact an older version as it is written in punchcard format.*

The lines in question are the ones beginning with 201.

I can resolve the issue simply by chosing 201 and 202 before each FORMAT section respectively, however there are other files reliant upon the argument 201 as statement number.

Can anyone tell if there is a solution to this?

Comment: Your code doesn't show any format statements labelled `201`.  Please look at how many of those there are and where they are/it is placed.  [But I may be confused as you seem to be expecting these labels to refer to files rather than formats?]

Comment: You can make your file shorter, but it must **reproduce the problem**! Take the *actual code*, delete stuff, and after it is short enough, but still has the problem, post it here. Do not post here any code, which does not contain the problem. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: a bit of an aside, but since you hit the same `write` regardless of `method` you should use a single `write` statement just after the `if` block.  You are mistaken in "file called 201" by the way. 201 is a reference to a format statement and has nothing to do with the file name or unit.

Comment: I realised after posting the code that the shortened version would work, so I have gone into more detail and best tried to recreate the problem. As I cannot post the original work I realised I missed important sections in my haste to try and get this solved.

Comment: As the error message states, you have two statements labelled `201`.  This isn't allowed.  Also, those statements labelled `201` are not valid format statements.  (Indeed, they aren't valid statements at all.)  What is it you expect/want to be happening?  [As a final note, you don't have Fortran 77 code at all, beyond the `201` problem.]

Comment: For clarity, given the first version of the question: the statements labelled `201` are those where the lines begin with `201`, not those where `201` is referenced in the `write` statements.  Given what you have written, are you expecting `x, y, i` to actually be part of the output list, so a continuation of the previous `write` statement?

Comment: I have no idea what the line `201 y,x,i ` is supoosed to do, but it certainly is not a valid Fortran statement.

Comment: I realise now this code is not 77, but maybe the older 66. I'm sorry to all of you who have taken the time to read my badly worded problem. I have updated again the original question.

Comment: Seeing those lines now: just delete one of them.

Comment: Will the program just go to the line beginning with 201 then to find the format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this warrants a full  explanation which does not fit in a comment. The FORMAT is not an executable statement. It just instructs the compiler in which format print or read DATA. There can always only be one `FORMAT` statement with the same label in a given scope. It does not matter on which line that exactly is.

In particular, when executing the `write`, `print` or `read` statement, the program does not in any way jump to the `FORMAT` statement. The compiler just uses the format description defined there.

Therefore:

```
          write(6,201) something
201       format('OUTPUT: ',i5,1p,7d10.2)
```

or

```
201       format('OUTPUT: ',i5,1p,7d10.2)
          write(*,201) something
```

or

```
201       format('OUTPUT: ',i5,1p,7d10.2)

          !many lines here

          write(*,201) something
```

or

```
          write(*,201) something

          !many lines here

201       format('OUTPUT: ',i5,1p,7d10.2)
```

or

```
  write(*,"('OUTPUT: ',i5,1p,7d10.2)") something
```

or

```
  write(*,"(i5,1p,7d10.2)") 'OUTPUT: ', something
```

will all do the same thing and all will work just fine.

The last way with a character constant (or variable) inside the write statement instead of the `FORMAT` statement label is the modern way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I understand now.

Comment: So the OP should basically just remove the `201` at the beginning of the `format` lines?

Comment: @Nike No, delete one of those two lines. There are two identical ones with the same label.

Answer (score 1):

`format` statements are not executable statements.  Except as noted below their location in the code isn't important.  So, while it may be tempting to put a format together with the output statement

```
      write(6,201) long,list,of,variables
201   format('OUTPUT: ',i5,1p,7d10.2)
```

that isn't necessary.  When one wants to duplicate that output a little later, simply copying the two lines doesn't help: the error message shown can pop up.

As detail: `write(unit=6,fmt=201)` (keywords added for clarity) is asking to write to unit 6 using the format of the `format` statement labelled `201` which occurs in the same inclusive scope of that `write`.  A line later `201  format (...)` is providing such a thing.

The error is that no two statements in the same scope may have the same label.  Deleting one of them, or changing the label (and its reference) would be suitable.

Vladimir F's answer goes into more detail about other approaches to address the format re-use.

Comment: I was worried that you only left the comment and the OP was still confused.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have now implemented this. Code is working fine, sometimes its the simple things that get me.